Where/how does fontforge get a 'fontid'/filename value?
I tried asking this question on the github discussions for the fontforge repository, but no one appears to be answering it.  I am using fontforge to generate SVG fonts for a php utility that generates SVG files from text strings.
Since I'm also trying to make a web-based gui to make generating these files easier, I'm also using fontforge to generate WOFF* equivalents.
While the final form will use a generate script, initially I was using the fontforge GUI and noticed it creates/suggests a uniform 'output' filename.
e.g. for Arial.ttf, output files are named ArialMT.woff or ArialMT.svg.  I also noticed in the SVG file that it sets the 'fontid' attribute to the same value.
However, looking in the headers (both in fontforge 'elements' tabs and using multiple ttf-meta parsing libraries in php) I can't seem to find a 1-to-1 field where this value is coming from.  So I suspect something in fontforge itself is sanitizing some other field to come up with this value.
I'm hoping to find out the 'rules' the method of coming up with this name follow (or if the value is hiding somewhere else, where to find it) so that I can generate names in my script that would be consistent with names generated by the GUI.
Does anyone know how fontforge comes up with it's suggestion for filename/fontid?
Looked in ttf headers, fontforge 'elements' tabs, dumped meta details with more than one php ttf-library tools.

Font files usually have multiple name records. In the case of "ArialMT" it seems like FF prefers the postScriptName entry. Otherwise it most likely skips to the next name entry and sanitizes the filename (e.g converting to camel case, removing spaces)

BTW. if you ultimate goal is to create a web-based gui I highly recommend testing JavaScript libraries like opentype.js which can directly generate SVG from given font files and text inputs. See codepen example A server-side conversion to svg fonts and eventually to svg images appears slightly complicated.

My question on the javascript based solution is whether or not it can generate an svg file from text. I built this tool around a CustomSVG library that performs that function. I need it to upload to print-on-demand services for customization.

I already have a generator/uploader working. What I'm trying to do now is move it from an older admin-panel library to filament and while doing so, I was hoping to add the ability to upload new fonts on the fly.  The problem is, regardless what is uploaded, I need an svg-font version for the 'tool' and either ttf or woff for displaying the type face in a browser.

For a short-term fix since the svg-font version is a deal breaker (if it can't convert to an svg font, I can't use it in the tool) I do a conversion then grab the fontid from the xml for naming the files.  Problem is, finding the best way to confirm that value should the file change. I'm basically running a to-/tmp-svg-font conversion before every conversion to get the name.

I did another quick search and found text-to-svg as an npm package. I think I'd tried that one before. It doesn't work with the primary font I want to use at all, and other fonts it doesn't seem to build the bounding box correctly and edges of the top and bottom get cut off.

I'm currently playing with one of the npm packages again to see if I can get it to work in a browser, as it would be useful to be able to handle my "translations" in real time. (not all fonts fit the default bounding box regardless what text-to-svg tool I have used, so include a 'translation' array that tells it when and how to translate/transform the font and/or change the size of the bounding box.)  At the time I built the original tool, the php version produced the best results and required an svg font.

At least I think it is quite over complicated to make node.js libraries work client-side when the heavy lifting (font parsing, font-to-svg rendering) is done by a lib which runs perfectly fine in a browser.  Please don't get me wrong – maybe your current php-parsing framework is the overall best solution for your needs.

I'll know in a day or two - converting my test code into class objects before running something like browserify or webpack on it to see if it will work.

I did play with opentype.js - that's how I was able to list the meta to see if anything consistently matched what font-forge was outputing.

Joy, opentype.js uses readFileSync which won't work in a browser and thus won't work for my needs. (Text2svg seems to be also using opentype.js)

Here's a simplified example creating a SVG from text and adjusting the viewBox. Obviously you need to send this output to a php script to save a static file on the server but that's also trivial. But frankly we moved quite far from the original question. If this approach appears promising please ask a new question with a detailed description about the desired output. Otherwise you also find quite a few examples on SO.

going to try playing with text-to-svg next in node. It also relies on opentype.js but claims it can load a font asynchronously in a browser. We'll see....
EDIT: it hadn't updated - I'll take a look at your examples also. Thanks for posting.

I've also added an answer here "How to convert text to SVG paths?". You don't need to browserify the node versions just use the prebuild opentype.js versions.

Your viewbox fit is great - are you manually adjusting that or doing it automated somehow? The tool I'm trying to create is something I use creating customizations on print-on-demand items. The PHP tool I just manually created the 'transform' data for each font I needed to use, but it required prepping that info running multiple tests before adding any new font. EDIT: I think I see it now with getBoundingBox() - nice!

Wow, yeah - that's a lot easier and solves a number of problems. I can go gut my code now as I don't think I'll need the transforms anymore. I'll have to do a test to see how well the svg drops into the various print-on-demand templates and if I can get the centering and scaling to work with the slightly different output.

With the advice from Heirstrietzel, I found a better solution for converting the fonts right in the browser or node.js using opentype.js.  And it should avoid having to store different versions of the font entirely or coming up with names for them.  The core of it from the browser side is an async function using the browser version of opentype.js.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@1.3.4/dist/opentype.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/ecmascript">
    const FONTDIR = './fonts/';

    function roundTwo(num) { return Math.round(num * 100) / 100; }

    async function svgFont(fontname='ArialMT', text=null, fontSize=24) {
        let fnbase = fontname.replace(/\.[^/.]{3,5}$/, "");
        if(text === null) text = fnbase;
        // assumes fonts are .ttf
        let fonturl = FONTDIR + fnbase + '.ttf';
        let buffer = await (await fetch(fonturl)).arrayBuffer();
        let font = opentype.parse(buffer);
        let pathOT = font.getPath(text, 0, fontSize, fontSize);
        let bb = pathOT.getBoundingBox();

        let newSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        newSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', [ roundTwo(bb.x1-1), roundTwo(bb.y1-1), roundTwo(bb.x2-bb.x1+2), roundTwo(bb.y2-bb.y1+1) ].join());
        let newPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
        newPath.setAttribute('d', pathOT.toPathData());
        newSvg.appendChild(newPath);
        return newSvg.outerHTML;
    }

</script>


Glad it helped. But please consider to rewrite your question (and title) to make it comprehensible and helpful for other/future users. The original question departs significantly from the final solution and thus doesn't make much sense for users searching for a fontforge related solution =)

dunno how I could word it differently I was looking for how to retrieve the name for one tool, and took your advice to use another tool that got rid of the need.  I am just pulling the postscript id now for something to ID the font(s) in the code, but don't need to use that ID to come up with a unique filename anymore as I can just use opentype.js to avoid the need to create a permanent svg font version.

I've refactored the code at least 4 times since. The code I'm using now barely resembles the one above, but I still have a copy of that for use in other stuff.
